# How do you step through an unisigned int?

Tags: variables, integer, int, typedef, unsigned

I am trying to step through an unsigned int and print the 0 and 1 values of each bit in my 32 bit number. So, for example, I am trying to write a code similar to:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
int main(){
     unit u = 0x21062910;
     int N=0; 
     for(int i=0; i < 32; i++){
           N = u[i]; 
           cout << N; 
     }
```

I know I can't access the individual bits like this, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. The desired output would be something like: `0010 0001 0000 0110 0010 1001 0001 0000`

Answer (score 0):

Change the third-to-last line to

```
           N = u & (1 << i);
```

That is, altogether:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
int main(){
     uint u = 0x21062910;
     uint N=0; 
     for(int i=0; i < 32; i++){
           N = u & (1 << i); 
           cout << N; 
}
```